# Returning list elements and indices

Tags: python

I am trying to print all the elements of a list using a user made function.

```
y = [1,2,3]
def ash(list1):
for x in range(len(list)):
    return list[x],x
```

what i want to do is return all the values in the list with their indices,but all i get is a single element.I can get the elements to print but not return.

Answer (score 5):

You are returning on the very first iteration. Rather, you need to create a list in your function, and add all the tuples in that list, and finally return that list.

And for getting both index and element, you can use `enumerate()`:

```
def ash(list1):
    new_list = []
    for x, elem in enumerate(list1):
        new_list.append((elem,x))
    return new_list
```

---

Or, even better you can simply use List comprehension:

```
return [(elem, x) for x, elem in enumerate(list1)]
```

---

The previous two methods creates the list in memory. If you have a very large list to deal with, then you should probably use generators, using `yield` keyword:

```
def ash(list1):
    for x, elem in enumerate(list1):
        yield elem, x
```

Comment: That's a terrible way to do this.

Comment: @Marcin. Can you explain?

Comment: Why are you appending to a list, rather than using a comprehension?

Comment: @Marcin. Already added the comprehension. Please refresh the page.

Comment: @Marcin. Can you remove your downvote now?

Comment: I still think your first snippet is a poor approach.

Comment: @Marcin. I've added that to show OP what was wrong with his code. And then I've added better alternative. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Really nice answer, showing the three most common ways to solve the problem!

Answer (score 2):

`enumerate(list)` is what you're looking for. ([see doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)). Also, calling `return` will give you only the first value of the list when calling the function, what you want here is probably the [`yield` statement](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators):

```
def ash(list):

  for i,item in enumerate(list):
    yield item,i

if __name__ == '__main__':

  y = [1,2,3]

  ys_with_indices = list(ash(y)) 
  print ys_with_indices
```

Note that this will return a generator object, which you have to convert to a list by calling list() on it. Alternatively, just use a normal list that you append the individual values to:

```
def ash(list):

  items_with_indices = []

  for i,item in enumerate(list):
    items_with_indices.append((item,i))

  return items_with_indices

if __name__ == '__main__':

  y = [1,2,3]

  ys_with_indices = ash(y)
  print ys_with_indices
```

Comment: While that's a better way to get values and indices out of a sequence, it doesn't solve the actual problem.

Comment: OK, I added an example that shows how to make a list from the generator and an alternative version using a normal list.

Comment: -1 use of `list` as variable name; appending to list instead of using comprehension.

Comment: wtf, I just used the variable name the author used in his question...

Answer (score 2):

Some issues with your code:

1. Don't iterate using `range` unless necessary. Iterate the list directly, or here, use `enumerate`
2. Don't use `list` as a variable - you'll shadow the built-in of the same name. It's confusing to the reader.
3. You're returning out of the loop. This is why you only get the first iteration. If you want to return successive values, use `yield`, which turns your function into a generator:

   ```
   def ash(l):
       for x in range(len(l)):
           yield l[x],x
   ```
4. This is really a reimplementation of `enumerate`:

   ```
   list(enumerate('abc')) #=> [(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
   ```
5. If you really want to swap the order of the pairs, you can do:

   ```
   [b,a for a,b in enumerate('abc')]
   ```
6. Alternative implementation: `l='abc';zip(l,xrange(len(l)))`

Answer (score 0):

```
def ash(lst):    
    return [(lst[x],x) for x in range(0,len(lst))]
```

You will get a list of tuples where the first value of the tuple is an element of the original list and the second the index of the element in the list.
For y = `[1,2,3]` the result is `[(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2)]`

Comment: Why iterate by index?

Comment: nice Pythonic solution.

Comment: @Marcin to get bot the index and the element of the list!

Comment: Use enumerate, or zip with range if you insist.